# Turn retrofit error into success

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm connecting to an API that can return several types of responses (explaining what went wrong) together with 500 error and I would like to process these responses in code together with normal 200 response, without Retrofit throwing exception in such case. It's easier that way, not to mention - the error thrown by Rertofit in case of 500 doesn't include the interesting response clarification in JSON format.

I was able to find info about `Interceptor`, but that doesn't get me far, the exception on 500 is still thrown:

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor {
                val response = it.proceed(it.request())

                if(response.code()==500) {
                    println("Here!")
                }

                response
            }
            .cookieJar(instance())
            .build()
```

What I need is to make Retrofit deserialize the JSON returned by 500 as it was regular reponse, and put it in `error` field of my regular response class. Is it possible? Note: all errors are returned as JSON object inside body of response.

Comment: First what is the error thrown by retrofit. Then can you show the code where you implement your call to the network.

Answer (score 1):

Since API format affects the entire app with the error handling behaviour, what you can do is change your interceptor to rewrite responses and modify the status code to 200 to avoid the exceptions thrown for a 500 response code.

However, be ***extremely cautious*** as this would be highly discouraged since it completely changes the way a particular HTTP status code is treated. Also, no error handling in the following snippet.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor {
val response = it.proceed(it.request())

if (response.code() == 500) {
    val mediaType = response.body()!!.contentType()
    val yourResponseObject = response.body()!!.string() // de-serialize response.body() to your response class and change fields as necessary
    val newResponse = response.newBuilder()
            .body(ResponseBody.create(mediaType, yourResponseObject)) //Create and set the response body
            .code(200)  //change the response code to a Success PROCEED WITH CAUTION!
            .build()
    return newResponse
}
return response
}
.cookieJar(instance())
.build()
```

This would rewrite your response to whatever your response class is, as you have access to the ResponseBody, and then changes your status code to a 200 Success to avoid ending up in an error/exception block

Further information: [OkHttp Github wiki: Interceptors - Rewriting Responses](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#rewriting-responses)